# Typo3 6.2.14 @inject repository

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I have created an extension with the extension-builder under Typ3 6.2.14.
Everything worked fine, but now I have encountered a problem with @inject, where I have found many hints in the WEB, but nothing works for me.

I am using 2 models (plant & speciesSelect). With the first one, everything works fine,

```
$plants = $this->plantRepository->findAll();
```

but with the second one

```
$speciesSelectAll = $this->speciesSelectRepository->findAll();
```

I always get: `"Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object.”`
But the really strange thing is, that I use the ‘@inject’ for the two models in the same way.

```
/**
 * plantRepository
 * 
 * @var \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Domain\Repository\PlantRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $plantRepository = NULL;
```

Here the second one:

```
   /**
 * speciesSelectRepository
 * 
 * @var \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Domain\Repository\SpeciesSelectRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $speciesSelectRepository = NULL;
```

For plant it works fine, for speciesSelect not.

I also have flushed all caches. I also deleted everything under typo3temp\Cache without any success.

Themn I tried to test the repository variables as you can see below.

```
    if ($speciesSelectRepository == NULL) {
        error_log('speciesSelectRepository is NULL', 0);
    } else {
        error_log('speciesSelectRepository is not NULL', 0);
```

In the error_log for both models I always find .. is NULL. But the strange thing is, that the findAll() function for plant works, but for speciesSelect not!

The only difference is, that for speciesSelect I make a manual call.

```
$speciesC = new \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\SpeciesSelectController();
$speciesC->speciesArrayAction();
```

Is maybe something wrong with using new()?
Are there additional things with @inject, which I have to care?

I know, @inject problems is often to find in this forum, but nothing is useful for me. Even that it works fine for plant but not for speciesSelect is not understandable for me.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Hans-Georg

Answer (score 2):

If below code:

```
/**
 * speciesSelectRepository
 * 
 * @var \HGA\Hgaplantdb\Domain\Repository\SpeciesSelectRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $speciesSelectRepository = NULL;
```

... is inside `\HGA\Hgaplantdb\Controller\SpeciesSelectController` and you create a new instants of this controller with the `new` keyword then the `@inject` wont be invoked.

Instead you should use:

```
$this->objectManager->get('\\HGA\\Hgaplantdb\\Controller\\SpeciesSelectController')
```

Above function takes care of injection of annotations. You should always use above instead of the `new` keyword when you work with ExtBase.

### Update

> Hi Lasse, I don't understand why, but it solved my problem. Thank you very much, Hans-Georg

You have to understand that `@inject`, `@lazy` or any other annotations just are PHP DocBlock (Comments) and that they do nothing magically on there own. So if you initialize a object with the `new` keyword then the property will have the value you assigned it: `null`.

If you however initialize the object with one of the following:

```
$this->objectManager->get('\\HGA\\Hgaplantdb\\Controller\\SpeciesSelectController')
```

or

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('\\HGA\\Hgaplantdb\\Controller\\SpeciesSelectController')
```

... then it should work after you have cleared your cache.

These methods will look your PHP DocBlocks over and if they find a syntax they recognize then they will do there magic. In most cases i would advise you to use `$this->objectManager->get()` whenever objectManager is available which it is in most ExtBase classes you extends. Else use the other one.

[`$this->objectManager->get` documentation](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/interface_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_object_1_1_object_manager_interface.html#a50b8f9886c021acb550d781d16608827)

[`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance` documentation](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_general_utility.html#a99623a1a2f1f8369d19d0e58c7feb4b0)

Comment: Hi Lasse,
I don't understand why, but it solved my problem.

Thank you very much,
Hans-Georg

Comment: Hi Hans-Georg. I have update my answer with some extra explanation. Hope its helps you understand it a little better.

Comment: By the way. Would you please mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue - thanks